# Function not showing a allert dialogue

Tags: flutter

I want to pick a time and date (using the package 'flutter_datetime_picker') and then, show a confirmation dialogue (using the package 'rflutter_alert.dart'). However, the confirmation diaglogue does not pop up, neither the date and time picker pops.

I've tried doing it in different functions but without any effects.

I have a RaisedButton and this is my onPressed function.

```dart
onPressed: () {
          confirmationDialogue();
          DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(
            context,
            theme: DatePickerTheme(
              doneStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              containerHeight: 300,
            ),
            currentTime: DateTime.now(),
            locale: LocaleType.en,
            showTitleActions: true,
            onConfirm: (date) {
              print(date);
              procFinishedDate = date;
              confirmationDialogue();
            },
          );
        },
```

This is the allert dialogue I want to show

```dart
void confirmationDialogue() {
    return new Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.warning,
      title: "STOP PROCESS",
      desc: "Are you sure you want to stop this process?",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "STOP",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // My Function
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "DON'T STOP",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ],
    ).show();
  }
```

Whenever I press the 'Done' button, it print the date, but does not show the dialogue. Any tips?

Comment: This might sound weird, but try calling confirmationDialogue() multiple times in a row. I've had an issue where I had to wrap a showDialog() call inside delayed Completer. Also try calling showDialog() directly to ensure that it's not an issue with the library.

Comment: I did what you told me and call the functions twice, and it worked somehow. I'll just do some more reasearch and try to understand why. Thanks for the tips.